# Detect error for google recaptcha execute

Tags: javascript, grecaptcha

How i can have an equivalent of .fail for grecaptcha.execute() if an error occurred, no connection or timeout connection i catch the error.

```
<script>
  function onClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    grecaptcha.ready(function() {
        grecaptcha.execute('reCAPTCHA_site_key', {action: 'submit'}).then(function(token) {
            // Code if no error
        });

        // Catch the error if occurred
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use try {} catch {} here:

```
grecaptcha.ready(async () => {
    try {
        const token = await grecaptcha.execute('reCAPTCHA_site_key', {action: 'submit'});
        // SUCCESS!
    } catch(err) {
        // ERROR!
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As the execute function is itself a Promise we can catch directly.

```
grecaptcha.ready(function() {
  grecaptcha.execute('reCAPTCHA_site_key', {action: 'submit'}).then(function(token) {
    // Code if no error
  }).catch(function(error) {
    // Code for error
  });
```

Comment: Does this apply to both recaptcha v3 and recaptcha v2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to just pass it into a try/catch block?

```
function onClick(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  try {
    grecaptcha.ready(function () {
      grecaptcha
        .execute("reCAPTCHA_site_key", { action: "submit" })
        .then(function (token) {
          // Code if no error
        });
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
  // Catch the error if occurred
}
```

Comment: Yes i tried this but the script catch not the error.

i disconnect voluntary my connexion for testing.

the error in console it's

POST https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/reload?k=<MyKey> net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED